# Is there some new keyword for return key in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7, bind

I am making a calculator and i bound the = button  to return keypress but it is not working. I have bound my button to an equal function and also to click function

```
def equal():
    if screenVal.get().isdigit():
        value = int(screenVal.get())
    else:
        try:
            value = eval(screenVal.get())
        except Exception:
            value = "Err"

    screenVal.set(value)
    screenEnt.update()


def click(event):
    global screenVal
    text = event.widget.cget("text")
    if text == "=":
        if screenVal.get().isdigit():
            value = int(screenVal.get())
        else:
            try:
                value = eval(screenVal.get())
            except Exception:
                value = "Err"

        screenVal.set(value)
        screenEnt.update()

    elif text == "C":
        screenVal.set("")
        screenEnt.update()
    else:
        screenVal.set(screenVal.get() + text)
        screenEnt.update()

    b = Button(frame, text="=",  padx=10, pady=10, font="consolas 15 bold", width=3, command=equal)
    b.pack(side=LEFT)
    b.bind('<Return>', click)
```

can anyone help?
I am working on python 3.7.9 on AMD 64

Comment: could you share your **equal** function as well?

Comment: `b.bind('<Return>', click)` shouldnt it be `b.bind('<Return>', equal)`

Comment: I have added the equal and click functions

Comment: @Cool Cloud not it cannot be

Comment: I tried that but it did not worl

Comment: What does "not working" mean - nothing happens?  An error is produced?  Something different happens?

Comment: @jasonharper no no error is produced its just that nothing happens to the program

Comment: You should bind it to the entry widget. or something that has focus rather than button

Comment: i have not done that.

Comment: Try that out and let me know

Comment: Not working bro

Comment: You need to shift the keyboard focus to the button and press `Enter` key.

Comment: you can try `bind_all` instead of `bind`

Comment: How do i do that @acw1668

Comment: Just keep pressing `Tab` key to shift the focus to the button.

Comment: @Wups from your comment i got the idea to bind root to the key and it works i just hadf to add *args parameter to the equal function

Comment: Thank you all for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

def equal():
    print('equal')

def click(event):
    print('click')

b = tk.Button(root, text="=",  padx=10, pady=10, font="consolas 15 bold", width=3, command=equal)
b.pack(side='left')
b.bind('<Return>', click)

root.mainloop()
```

If you run this script the `equal` command works as expected. What your problem seems to be is, that you cant execute the `return` binding. The event only happens if the keyboard-focus is on that button, try by pressing tab till the button have focus.

A solution could be to bind it to the frame or even better to the window. Like in the exampel below.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

def equal():
    print('equal')

def click(event):
    print('click')

b = tk.Button(root, text="=",  padx=10, pady=10, font="consolas 15 bold", width=3, command=equal)
b.pack(side='left')
root.bind('<Return>', click)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: we will have to do `root.bind('<Return>', equal) because click function evaluates only if the = button is pressed

Comment: Of course you can change the function. I dont understand whats wrong with the answer.